# Compiling same header with different compilation flag in different compilation units

Tags: c++, compilation, inline, conditional-compilation

I've encountered a strange problem that kind of breaks what I understand about a compilation unit's encapsulation.

In a nutshell I have a common inlined function that I get from a header.
I include that into 2 different .cpp files, with a different `#define` macros.
But I end up getting the same implementation in bot compilation units.

Common.h:

```
#include <iostream>

inline void printA()
{
#ifdef YES
    std::cout << " yes" << std::endl;
#else
    std::cout << " no" << std::endl;
#endif
}
```

File1.h:

```
void print1();
```

File1.cpp:

```
#define YES
#include "Common.h"
#include "File1.h"

void print1()
{
    printA();
}
```

File2.h:

```
void print2();
```

File2.cpp

```
#include "Common.h"
#include "File2.h"
void print2()
{
    printA();
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "File1.h"
#include "File2.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    print1();
    print2();

    return 0;
}
```

The output to this example is:

```
yes
yes
```

I would expect it to be:

```
yes
no
```

So, why is the same implementation taken in both compilation units ?
The common function is even inlined....

How can I get my "expected" result?

And, why is the "yes" implementation chosen ? Just a matter of compilation order?

BTW, I get the same results on GCC 4.8 and VS2012

Comment: in file2.cpp, you include 'file.h' which i don't see.

Comment: Please **edit your post** with the contents of *Common.h*.

Comment: I still see file.h included in file2.cpp

Comment: It's a typo, file.h is common.h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard (here N4527) says in **3.2 One definition rule**/6

> There can be more than one definition of a class type (Clause 9), enumeration type (7.2), inline function with
>   external linkage (7.1.2), class template (Clause 14), non-static function template (14.5.6), static data member
>   of a class template (14.5.1.3), member function of a class template (14.5.1.1), or template specialization for
>   which some template parameters are not specified (14.7, 14.5.5) in a program provided that each definition
>   appears in a different translation unit, and provided the definitions satisfy the following requirements. Given
>   such an entity named D defined in more than one translation unit, then
>   (6.1)
>
> — each definition of D shall consist of the same sequence of tokens; and

...

> If the definitions of D satisfy all these requirements,
>   then the behavior is as if there were a single definition of D. If the definitions of D do not satisfy these
>   requirements, then the behavior is undefined.

So replacing "yes" with "no" is an ODR-violation, causing undefined behavior.

For the result of getting "yes" I can guess that the compiler picks one function at random, as they *have to* be identical.

On the other hand, if you made the function `static`, you would have different local functions in each translation unit.